# How to align center of two elements in one line vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

This is a tricky situation, so I could not explained it properly in the title. But I tried.

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yCjnz/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') repeat-y center center;
}

.parent {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    top: 32px;
}
```

There are two elements and I want them to appear like this:

[image]

So that the center of one element will align with the center of the other element. I can't use `left: -50px` for the `.child` element, as the `width` of both the elements vary. How can I achieve the result using CSS? I can also use JavaScript and jQuery, but I would like to have a solution in CSS, if possible.

Comment: Instead of the child element being a child - could it be placed after the parent element?

Comment: check your fiddle again...http://jsfiddle.net/yCjnz/7/

Comment: @Danield No, the child element can't be placed after the parent element.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, don't place them inside one another e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/FzBtv

HTML:

```
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top:1px;
}
```

Comment: No, the child element can't be placed after the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent , .child {
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEzNDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNSBNYWNpbnRvc2giIHhtcE1NOkluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6QUJFQUREODEyODE0MTFFM0FCNEZBREFCODAxMTcwMjkiIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6QUJFQUREODIyODE0MTFFM0FCNEZBREFCODAxMTcwMjkiPiA8eG1wTU06RGVyaXZlZEZyb20gc3RSZWY6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDpBQkVBREQ3RjI4MTQxMUUzQUI0RkFEQUI4MDExNzAyOSIgc3RSZWY6ZG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDpBQkVBREQ4MDI4MTQxMUUzQUI0RkFEQUI4MDExNzAyOSIvPiA8L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4gPC9yZGY6UkRGPiA8L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4gPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0iciI/Ppi8nlwAAAAOSURBVHjaYmBgYAAIMAAABAABmwPqCQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') repeat-y center center;
}

.parent {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yCjnz/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately child elements comes inside the the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code.  The main one is that your parent's width is smaller than the child's width.  I'm not sure why this is, frankly.  The second problem is that your child has `position: absolute;` - this will effectively set it at the specific pixel point - or 0 if not specified explicitly.  I made a few changes to your code:

- made parent's width larger than the child's width
- removed `position: absolute` from the child and changed its `top` to `margin-top`
- set child's `margin` to `auto`

Here's the [jsfiddle of the result](http://jsfiddle.net/yCjnz/5/)

Comment: The width of elements are variable. So, I can't be sure, whether width of the the parent element will be more than that of child element. In most of the cases, width of the child element is more than width of the parent element. So, this solution does not work in my case.

Comment: @Debiprasad If the child's width is more than the parent's width, then your DOM is not correct.  I strongly advise you to review how your DOM is structured and have the two elements as siblings and not a parent of one another.

Comment: There is no problem with the DOM. The width of the elements vary depending on the length of the elements. The DOM is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TENdH/

Comment: @Debiprasad You've got text lists there.  Why don't you show with the specific data what you're trying to achieve, rather than an abstract blocks?

Comment: I thought it will be easy to explain the situation with less code.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your markup I couldn't think of any pure CSS solution; however, with jQuery, it's very easy to achieve: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCjnz/12/))

```
var $child = $('.child');
var $parent = $('.parent');

$child.css('left','-'+(Math.abs($child.width()-$parent.width())/2)+'px');
```

Since both sizes may vary, even CSS3 `calc()` function will not help here.

As @Tyron noticed, the `.child` if off by 1px because of its left-border. You can fix that by adding:

```
.child{margin-left:-1px;} /* 1px being border-left's width */
```

Comment: In your jsfiddle, the elements are still off by one pixel in Chrome/Firefox

Comment: Thank you. This solution was in my mind. However I wanted to find a solution in CSS, if possible. I am waiting for more answers for CSS. Else, this will be the final solution.

Comment: @Debiprasad no worries, glad to help anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

is there a specific reason the bigger element must be nested in the smaller element?

http://jsfiddle.net/yCjnz/10/

i swapped the attributes around and changed the positions (swopped the parent and the child)

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin:0px auto;
  top:32px;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  top:-32px;
}
```

Comment: When I saw your code, first I thought that you have given the same solution as Aleks G. Then for few seconds I thought that you have got the solution. And then I realised that you replaced child with parent and parent with child with your CSS.